# Composition series interpretation with the 4th isomorphism theorem

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I was trying to get some insight into the definition of composition series and I'll appreciate it if someone verifies my understanding.

I am comprehending that if we were to draw the lattice of a group there will always be a normal subgroup in the immediate next "level" of the lattice. By the 4th isomorphism the composition factor $G_{i+1} /G_i$ is simple. This will continue until we reach the trivial subgroup of G.

Is this correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Please be more precise about what you mean by "level".

Comment: By next level, I mean the biggest proper subgroups of G drawn in the lattice.

Comment: That's better. Thank you :)